# Proving equality of matrix

Tags: matrices

$A$ and $B$ are two real skew symmetric matrix then prove that $A$$B$$=$$B$$A$. Please help me . Give me hints please.

Comment: Do you know what "skew symmetric" means?

Comment: This is not true when the sizes of the matrices are larger than 2. It's true for $2\times2$ skew symmetric matrices, though.

Comment: But how shall I solve ?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ is skew symmetric if $A = -A^T$. In terms of the entries of $A$, it means $A$ has the form

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Similarly $B$ must be of the form

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\ -b & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now compute $AB$ and $BA$ explicitly and check that they are identical.

Comment: I understood this but how shall I solve without example? .

Comment: @user435358: What do you mean? If the matrices are not $2 \times 2$ then the result is not true and if the matrices are $2 \times 2$, then just write them and multiply them.

Comment: If the matrix is in different form then what shall I do ?

Comment: @user435358: It cannot be in different form because it is skew symmetric.

Comment: OK I understood

Comment: @user435358: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) if you found it helpful.